# How to add header for total summary row in DevExpress Grid

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

I want to add TotalSummary header in gridview first columns. But I don't add.
Can you help me?

[image: Exp._Picture]

Comment: The solution depends on the platform. Add to the question the platform you are using - ASP.NET, WinForms, WPF, or else

Comment: Ohh, I am sorry I forgot to write platform. I am using ASP.Net

Comment: You said you have tried something but it doesn't work. What is your code so far? Give us a sample

Comment: Also what do you mean by "TotalSummary header"? Do you mean displaying the Total Summary in the header instead of the footer of the grid?